# insert a data into mysql database if the field valus is change

Tags: django, python-2.7, django-models

I have developed a code for update a database,but right now I want to code if the value is change the database insert the data not update the database.Here is my code:-

```
 def update_Sprint(self, ps):
    id = ps.projectid
    data=requests.get('https://example.com/api/v1/xyz/'+str(ps.projectid)+'/Iterations?include=[Id,Name,StartDate,EndDate,UserStories-Effort-Sum,UserStories-EffortCompleted-Sum]&token='+settings.AUTH_TOKEN+'&format=json')
    data=json.loads(data.text)
    data=data['Items']
    if len(data)>0:
        for data_ in data:
            sprint_id=str(data_['Id']

            sps = Day.objects.filter(sprintid=sprint_id, project__projectid=ps.projectid)

            print '     creating new sprint '+str(sprint_id)
            sp = Day(sprintid=sprint_id, project=ps)
            sp = update_model(sp, sprint_name = Name,sprint_end_date = EndDate, sprint_start_date = StartDate, usesteff_sum = Effor_Sum,usesteffc_sum = Effort_Com,)
            #self.update_story(sp)
            #self.update_Bug(sp)
```

def update_model(obj, **params):
    """

```
:param obj: generic model object
:param params: fields, value dict of the obj's model
:return: updated object
"""
is_updating = False
for key in params:
    try:
        field = getattr(obj, key)
        value = params[key]
        if field==value:
            print 'same value'
        elif ((not value) and (not field)): print 'No value for '+key
        else:
            print 'updating value'
            is_updating = True
            setattr(obj, key, value)
            # obj.field = value
    except AttributeError as ex:
        print ex
if is_updating:
    obj.save()
return obj
```

How can I insert the data into database if the field and value are not same.I don't want to update the table.

Comment: have you tried set the force_update to True
(https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/ref/models/instances/#saving-objects)[https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/ref/models/instances/#saving-objects]

Comment: Is there any solution??